# Why is C++ getline() non-blocking when program is called from python subprocess?

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, getline

I have a C++ program that waits for some text input with `getline()`, and it works well from the command line.

However, I would like to call it from Python - send some text, get the output, and have it wait for more input.

I tried with `subprocess`, but it seems that `getline()` in this case doesn't wait for input but gets an empty line. It works as intended if I constantly send input, but as soon as I stop doing that, it starts reading empty strings.

Adding `if (!input_command.empy())` in C++ works, but in this way the program consumes a lot of resources (I suppose because it keeps cycling the loop).

Is it possible to have `getline()` stop and wait for some actual input?

C++:

```cpp
bool ExitProg = FALSE;
do{
    string input_command;
    getline(cin, input_command)
       
    if (input_command == std::string("something")){
        cout << "something" << endl;
    }
    
    if (input_command == std::string("exit")){
        ExitProg = True;
    }
    
} while (!ExitProg)
```

Python:

```py
process = subprocess.Popen('c_program.exe', stdin=subproces.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write('something\n')
process.stdin.flush()
print(process.stdout.readline())
```

UPDATE:
I assumed that the program was reading empty lines for the following reason. In the C++ program, I split the input line into an array and, when the python code was finished, I was getting an error from the C++ program about an element of the array not existing.

Comment: When you close the pipe providing the input, the input operation fails. You never check for success, so it runs around the loop and immediately tries input again. Since the streamstate is already in failure, it just returns and you have an endless loop. Oh, and no, it doesn't get an empty line, it fails!

Comment: "*Is it possible to have `getline()` stop and wait for some actual input?*" - it already does exactly that. `getline()` does not exit until either the specified delimiter (`'\n'` by default) is encountered, or the I/O stream reaches EOF, or I/O fails.

Comment: I added an `if` to check if the cin is in fail status (`if (!cin.fail())`) and if it is I added `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore(1000, '\n')` but the problem is still the same. Also from python I don't close the input pipe, so I don't understand why it should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a class and added the start of the subprocess to the `__init__` method. The methods of the class are used to interact with the C++ program. At this point however I was still having the same issue.

I solved it by adding a `__del__` method that terminates the subprocess.